# How to count IDs, where another column is equal to exact values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `user_activity` like as displayed below and I need to count `user_id`, where `comp_id` should equal to 2 values. In this example to 125 and 126:

```
|comp_id| user_id|
 125         1
 126         1
 127         1
 125         2
 126         2
 127         3
 .           .
 .           .
 .           .
 .           .
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
|comp_id| comp_id| count_userID|
 125        126         2
 126        127         1
 127        125         2
```

I wrote subquery `temp`, where I firstly chose `comp_id` = `125` and join to `user_activity` and counted them nicely:

```
with temp as(select
  ss.user_id
from
  user_activity ss
where ss.comp_id = 125
)
  
select
  ss.comp_id,
  count(temp.user_id)
from temp left join user_activity ss
```

But I have 8000 different variations and I should it automate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self `join` and aggregation.  If I understand correctly:

```
select ua.comp_id, ua2.comp_id, count(*)
from user_activity ua join
     user_activity ua2
     on ua.user_id = ua2.user_id and
        ua.comp_id < ua2.comp_id
group by ua.comp_id, ua2.comp_id;
```

I'm not sure if you want `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT ua.user_id)`.